# building large strings of unknown length in c

Tags: c, performance

I've no doubt there is an answer to this somewhere, I just can't find it.

I have just returned to c after a long break and am very rusty, so please excuse dumb errors. I need to generate a large (maybe equivilent of 10mb) string. I don't know how long it's going to be until it's built.

I tried the following two approaches to test speed:

```
int main() {
#if 1
  size_t message_len = 1; /* + 1 for terminating NULL */
  char *buffer = (char*) malloc(message_len);
  for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
  {
    int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d \n", i);
    char * a = malloc(size + 1);
    sprintf(a, "%d \n", i);

    message_len += 1 + strlen(a); /* 1 + for separator ';' */
    buffer = (char*) realloc(buffer, message_len);
    strncat(buffer, a, message_len);
  }
#else
  FILE *f = fopen("test", "w"); 
  if (f == NULL) return -1; 
  for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
  {
    fprintf(f, "%d \n", i);
  }
  fclose(f);
  FILE *fp = fopen("test", "r");
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  long fsize = ftell(f);
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  char *buffer = malloc(fsize + 1);
  fread(buffer, fsize, 1, f);
  fclose(fp);
  buffer[fsize] = 0;
#endif
  char substr[56];
  memcpy(substr, buffer, 56);
  printf("%s", substr);
  return 1;
}
```

The first solution of concatenating strings each time took 3.8s, the second of writing to a file then reading took 0.02s.

Surely there is a fast way to build a big string in c without resorting to reading and writing to a file? Am I just doing something very inefficient? If not can I write to some kind of file object, then read it at the end and never save it?

In C# you would use a stringbuffer to avoid the slow concatination, what's the equivilent in c?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any specific reason you're not just `realloc`'ing with an accumulated point-of-write based on `size` values and just blasting the string directly at that offset, thereby avoiding the additional `malloc` and `free` (the *missing* `free`, btw)? Also, using `strcat` as you are you're introducing the classic [Painter's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm).

Comment: You've implemented [Shelmiel the Painter's Algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) - a recommeded and very relevant read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making life pretty rough with these lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
  {
    int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d \n", i);  // << executed in first loop only
    char * a = malloc(size + 1);               // allocate enough space for "0 \n" + 1
    sprintf(a, "%d \n", i);                    // may try to squeeze "199999 \n" into a

    message_len += 1 + strlen(a); /* 1 + for separator ';' */
    buffer = (char*) realloc(buffer, message_len);
    strncat(buffer, a, message_len);
  }
```

You compute `size` and allocate space for `a` in the first iteration - then proceed to use it in every subsequent iteration (where `i` gets bigger, and you will in principle exceed the storage allocated for `a`). If you did this correctly (allocating size for `a` in each loop) you would have to `free` in every loop as well, or create a giant memory leak.

The solution, in C, is to pre-allocate plenty of memory - and only reallocate in emergency. If you know "roughly" how big your string will be, allocate all that memory at once; keep track of how big it is, and add more if you run short. At the end you can always "give back what you didn't use". Too many calls to `realloc` keep moving memory around (since you often don't have enough contiguous memory available where you were).  As @Matt clarified in his comment: there is a real risk that every call to `realloc` **moves the entire block of memory** - and as the block gets bigger, that becomes a quadratically increasing load on the system. Here is a possible better solution (complete, tested with small N and BLOCK just to show the principle; you will want to use large N (your value of 200000), and larger BLOCK - and get rid of the `printf` statements that were there to show things are working ):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 2000000 
#define BLOCK 32 
int main(void) {
size_t message_len = BLOCK; //
  char *buffer = (char*) malloc(message_len);
  int bb;
  int i, n=0;
  char* a = buffer;
  clock_t start, stop;
  for(bb = 1; bb < 128; bb *= 2) {
  int rCount = 0;
  start = clock();
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    a = buffer + n;
    n += sprintf(a, "%d \n", i);
    if ((message_len - n) < BLOCK*bb) {
      rCount++;
      message_len += BLOCK*bb;
      //printf("increasing buffer\n");
      //printf("increased buffer to %ld\n", (long int)message_len);
      buffer = realloc(buffer, message_len);
    }
  }
  stop = clock();
  printf("\nat the end, buffer length is %d; rCount = %d\n", strlen(buffer), rCount);
//  buffer = realloc(buffer, strlen(buffer+1));
  //printf("buffer is now: \n%s\n", buffer);
  printf("time taken with blocksize = %d: %.1f ms\n", BLOCK*bb, (stop - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  }
}
```

You will want to use a fairly large value for `BLOCK` - this will limit the number of calls to `realloc`. I would use something like 100000; you get rid of the space at the end anyway.

**EDIT** I modified the code I had posted to allow timing of the loop - increasing N to 2 million to get "reasonable times". I also minimized the initial memory allocation (to force a lot of calls to `realloc` and fixed a bug (when `realloc` had to move memory, `a` was no longer pointing to an offset in `buffer`. That is fixed now by keeping track of the string length so far in `n`.

This is pretty fast - 450 ms for the smallest block, dropping to 350 ms for larger blocks (2 million numbers). That is comparable (within the resolution of my measurement) to your file read/write operation. But yes - file I/O streaming and associated memory management are highly optimized...

Comment: +1: I think the key to this question's performance is understanding that realloc can (and likely will, when called this often) copy the contents of memory if there's not enough space after the original pointer. That is, if there's not enough free heap after the original buffer, realloc must allocate a new, big-enough buffer somewhere else and _copy the entire contents of the original buffer to the new location_. Good job pointing this out.

Comment: @Matt - thanks for your point. I decided to be more explicit in my statement; you were right it was what I intended to say, but I'm not sure it was completely clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Interestingly with the printf removed and and block sized increased a lot it's still marginally slower than the file write/read solution I suggested at the beginning!

Answer (score 1):

`c` has no objects so there's no equivalent to the `C#` stringbuffer (though in `C++` you would use `std::string`).

You would get a performance boost by not calling realloc on every append, and never calling malloc the way you are.

You can avoid your malloc completely by simply declaring a char[] large enough to print the largest int into; this would avoid the snprintf too, and the size is fairly small.

Instead of *constantly* calling realloc, you should grow your buffer by some reasonable size… say 4kb (a nice size to correspond with page size), and only grow it again when it comes close to being exhausted (that is, when its current usage is less than the array size you use above from the top).

Answer (score 1):

I have left out some details, but my approach is generally like this

create a structure like this one

```
typedef struct {
    char *curr ;
    char *start ;
    char *end ;
} VBUF ;
```

write some functions along these lines:

```
void vbuf_alloc(VBUF *v,int n)
{
    v->start = malloc(n) ;
    v->end = v->start + n ;
    v->curr = v->start ;
    }

int vbuf_add(VBUF *v,char *s,int length)
{
    if (v->end - v->curr < length) {
        vbuf_realloc(v,(v->end - v->start) * 2) ;
        }
    memcpy(v->curr,s,length) ;
    v->curr += length ;
    return length ;
    }

int vbuf_adds(VBUF *v,char *s)
{
    return vbud_add(v,s,strlen(s)) ;
    }
```

You can extend this suite of functions as much as you like.

Comment: This would suffer from the same constant realloc his existing code does, and would do nothing to prevent his existing performance-sucking-and-unnecessary snprintf and malloc. You've provided a nice formalized structure but it doesn't solve the problem that was posed.

Comment: err no, it reallocates only when the string has doubled in size. Depending upon the first allocation size, you may not have very many reallocations. The sprintf part is his choice, I was just dealing with a method of extending strings in an efficient way.

Comment: I did miss that however on looking again, it looks like you've got a bug in determining when to realloc… you're comparing end-start to length, but shouldn't you be comparing end-curr?

Comment: yea, maybe a bit too rushed. Thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead of `realloc` on every successive string, attempt to intelligently `realloc` ahead of time if the length is too short. In other words, avoid realloc whenever possible.

A naive implementation in pseudocode might be something like

```
Initialize an int/long to "written so far"
Initialize an int/long to remember "buffer size"
Alloc memory for a string up to the "buffer size"
Read in the next chunk into a temporary buffer
Get the "chunk size" from the temporary buffer
If "written so far" + "chunk size" > "buffer size"
    Reallocate the chunk to be much bigger (double "buffer size"?)
    Set the new "buffer size"
Copy the data from the temporary buffer to "buffer address" + "written so far" + 1
Set "written so far" to "written so far" + "chunk size"
```

I just threw this together, so there may be indexing errors, but you get the idea: only allocate and copy when you *have* to, instead of every time through the loop.